# TRPC Handle TRPCError

Tags: next.js, trpc

I am making an app with next js and trpc, when I make a query with trpc and trhow an error occurs, the client side does not receive the error.

My Page:

```
"use client"

import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { trpc } from "../_trpc/client";
import { Loader2 } from "lucide-react";
    
const Page = () => {

    const router = useRouter()
    const searchParams = useSearchParams()
    const origin = searchParams.get("origin")

    const { data: user, isLoading, isSuccess, error } = trpc.authCallback.useQuery(undefined, {
        retry: true,
        retryDelay: 500
    })

    console.log(error) // always returns null

    return (
        <div className="w-full mt-24 flex justify-center">
            <div className="flex flex-col items-center gap-2">
                <Loader2 className="h-8 w-8 animate-spin text-zinc-800" />
                <h3 className="font-semibold text-xl">
                    Setting up your account...
                </h3>
                <p>
                    You will be redirected automaticly
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Page;
```

TRPC code:

```
    import { createDbUser, getDbUser, getKindeUser } from '@/services/auth';
    import { publicProcedure, router } from './trpc';
    import { TRPCError } from '@trpc/server'
    import { getKindeServerSession } from '@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server';
    import { db } from '@/db';
    
    export
      const appRouter = router({
        // query to get data
        // mutation to modify data
    
        authCallback: publicProcedure.query(async () => {
/// ...
            throw new TRPCError({ code: 'UNAUTHORIZED' }) // throw this error to handle it on my page.tsx

/// ...
          return { success: true }
        })
      });
    
    // Export type router type signature,
    // NOT the router itself.
    export type AppRouter = typeof appRouter;
```

Does anyone know why I'm not getting the error on my client side? I already tried onError, but it seems that this function was removed on the new trpc update.

when I call this "http://localhost:3000/api/trpc/call-back" on my browser, I do see the error. So the error is being sent but it doesn't get to the client side??

Answer (score 0):

If what I think is correct, you and I are practicing with the same project, and I had the same problem.

If you've got a HTTP-405 then change what you'll have to change what you're exporting const handler as ->

```js
    import { fetchRequestHandler } from "@trpc/server/adapters/fetch";
    import { appRouter } from '@/trpc';
    import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
    
    const handler = (req: NextRequest) => fetchRequestHandler({
        endpoint: '/api/trpc',
        req,
        router: appRouter,
        createContext: () => ({}),
    });
    
    export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Also consider adding these lines to your .gitignore file

```
    .env*.local
    .env
    .env.local
    .env.staging
```

This is because making your PrismaDB credentials invalidates them immediately, if you've noticed, you always get an email from PlanetscaleDB saying it's been invalidated, so if that's the case;

2. Create new credentials for your PrismaDB and push changes to the database

```bash
    npx prisma db push
```

3. Sign in to your server on localhost before going to the /auth-callback route because at that moment there's no existing user to work with.

Answer (score 0):

along with the onSuccess change,

which is this -

```
   const { data, error } = trpc.authCallback.useQuery(undefined);

      useEffect(() => {
        if (data?.success) {
          router.push(origin ? `/${origin}` : "/dashboard");
        } else if (error?.data?.code === "UNAUTHORIZED") {
          console.log('error: ', error);
          router.push("/sign-in");
        }
      }, [data, error, router, origin]);
```

and adding await before every getUser worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify the `useQuery` option `retry` like below to access the `error` object:

```
const { data, isSuccess } = trpc.authCallback.useQuery(undefined, {
        retry: (failureCount, error) => {
            if (failureCount > threshold) {
                //Do Something or Nothing
            }
            if (error.data?.code === errorCode) {
                // operations to perform on this errorCode
            }
            // return false at any point to exit out of retry loop
            return true;
        },
        retryDelay: 500,
    })
```